# Waiting for a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have the problem, that my function runs, before the other one ends.
I tried to runs the function GetCategories in GetEntries, but that doesn't work for me.

GetEntries only works with an empty string because the functions is executed too early. Although there are categories in the useEffect function, the function is not rerender. Please help.

```
import ...


export default function CFramework() {
  const year = GetYears();
  const title = GetCategories();
  const entries = GetEntries(title);
  const factor = GetFactor(title);

  return 
    <>
      <p>{year}</p>
      <p>Title: {title}</p>
      <p>Entries: {entries}</p>
      <p>Factor: {factor}</p>
   </>
```

GetCategories:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Parse from "parse";

function GetCategories() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCategories();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  async function getCategories() {
    const Categories = Parse.Object.extend("BerechnungsKategorie");
    const query = new Parse.Query(Categories);
    await query.find().then(function (results) {
      results.forEach((e) => {
        categories[parseInt(e.get("ID"))] = e.get("Name");
      });
    });
    setCategories([...categories]);
  }
  return categories;
}

export default GetCategories;
```

GetFactor:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Parse from "parse";
import GetCategories from "./GetCategories";

export default function GetEntries(categories) {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    async function getValues() {
      categories.forEach((c, index) => {
        getEntries(c, index);
      });

      async function getEntries(category, index) {
        var temp = [];
        var q = new Parse.Query("BerechnungsKategorie");
        q.equalTo("Name", category);
        var results = await q.find();
        results.forEach((element, index) => {
          var q = new Parse.Query("BerechnungsEintrag");
          q.equalTo("Kategorie", category);
          q.find().then(function (category) {
            category.forEach((e, index) => {
              temp[index] = e.get("Name");
            });
            entries[index] = temp;
            if (entries.length === categories.length) {
              setEntries([...entries]);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
    getValues();
    console.log(categories);

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, categories);

  return entries;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use react functional components as normal functions or use react context if you want persist the state globally

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
      const [entries, setEntries] = useState([])
    
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const title = await getCategories();
        const entries = getEntries(title); // create function accroiding to that
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }, [categories]);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback version of the other answer:

```
export default function CFramework() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const title = GetCategories().then(() => {
       // wait for GetCategories=^
        const entries = GetEntries(title);
    });
  }, []);

  return 
    <>
      <p>{year}</p>
      <p>Title: {title}</p>
      <p>Entries: {entries}</p>
      <p>Factor: {factor}</p>
   </>
}
```

Side note: you need to adjust the utility functions/services to return promises

Comment: If I try this, I get an invalid hook call, cause I use hooks in GetCategories. It is easy to fix?